# equality of data.frames where one column is a list

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is an example from [Hadley Wickham's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) to generate a `data.frame` that has a column that is list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:3)
df1$y <- list(1:2,1:3,1:4)
```

He goes on to explain that it is also possible to create the `data.frame` as

```
df2 <- data.frame(x=1:3,y=I(list(1:2,1:3,1:4)))
```

Both return

```
  x          y
1 1       1, 2
2 2    1, 2, 3
3 3 1, 2, 3, 4
```

My question: Can I check that `df1` and `df2` are "identical", and if so, how?

I tried `all.equal(df1,df2)`, which gives (sorry for working on a German installation)

```
[1] "Component “y”: Attributes: < Ziel ist NULL, aktuell ist list >"
```

and `identical(df1,df2)` which gives

```
[1] FALSE
```

as well as `all(df1==df2)`, which returns

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : comparison of these types is not implemented
```

Comment: What about `all.equal(df1, df2, check.attributes = FALSE)`?

Comment: Would you care to educate me why this is off-topic? I confess to not understanding the "specific reason".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not identical, which is what `identical()` is checking, they have different classes...

```
str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3
 $ y:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 2
  ..$ : int  1 2 3
  ..$ : int  1 2 3 4
str(df2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3
 $ y:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 2
  ..$ : int  1 2 3
  ..$ : int  1 2 3 4
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Similar to this:

```
> a <- 1:3
> b <- 1:3
> class(b) <- "aaa"
> a
[1] 1 2 3
> b
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "aaa"
> identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE
> a==b
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```